# Is that possible to give admin access to normal user and restrict to edit profile?

Tags: administration, profile, permission-sets

Our project is running on secured environment. So we add IP to profile to restrict access outside of the organization. Its strictly followed in production org. But when we give dev sandbox access to developer we give admin permission to them. Some people edit the IP of admin profile and try to access outside of the organization.

So we are thinking to give admin request but not to give permission on edit IP in profile. Will that possible. ?

i am trying to change the standard user to admin user by adding permission set and system permission in profile.

Any Idea or suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Refer the documentation - [Set Trusted IP Ranges for Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_networkaccess.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0).

As you cannot change permissions on Standard profile, Try cloning the required standard profile and disable appropriate permissions mentioned below.

1. To view network access:

   - `Login Challenge Enabled`
2. To change network access:

   - `Manage IP Addresses`

Note: One catch is, Restricted admins can still login as some other administrator and enable it back. To avoid that, disable [login as](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enabling-Organization-Admins-Can-Login-as-Any-User&type=1) for those users.

Comment: +10 Yes. Rahul. It still allow user to edit/delete the IP ranges. "Manage Profiles and Permission Sets" permission restrict profile itself. I trying. I will update if can break the permission.